# Select every 15min from start time to end time

Tags: mysql

For example, suppose that the start time is 4:01pm and the stop time is 5.50pm, I would like to select every 15min record including the start time and stop time.

| field1 | field2 | timestamp (datetime) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Start time, select me |  | 4:01pm |
| Don't select me |  | 4:02pm |
|  |  | ... |
| Don't select me |  | 4:15pm |
| select me |  | 4:16pm |
|  |  | ... |
| select me |  | 4:31pm |
|  |  | ... |
| stop time, select me |  | 5:50pm |

I searched online and I only found solutions that yields the following results:
4:15pm, 4.30pm, 4.45pm...

```sql
SELECT   FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)/(15 * 60)) AS timekey
FROM     table
GROUP BY timekey;
```

Comment: And the question is???   Perhaps you are saying that if there is no data within a 15 min period, you get no row?

Comment: Hi Rick, I would like to select records in between a certain time frame, eg, from `4:01pm to 4:41pm, every 15 min`.

What I am hoping to get is the following result:
`4:01pm, 4.16pm, 4:31pm, 4:41pm`

Comment: there will always be records as the database table contains records of sensor readings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start at 4:01 instead of 4:00, you may need an adjustment:

```
FLOOR((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) - 1 * 60)/(15 * 60))
```

To convert `timekey` back to "4:01", do

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(timekey * 15 * 60 + 1 * 60);
```

(change the 1 to 15 to get 4:15)